# Best way to share code between high school programming students in groups

Tags: java, eclipse, version-control, collaboration

I would like to have my programming students work in groups and make a program using Eclipse and Java. I've been researching the best way to have students collaborate on such a program but I don't know the best for them to work together.

Ultimately, I would like one student to make a class, another student to make another class and then have them import the other student's class into their project and call the necessary methods within the class.

Bitbucket and GitHub are confusing to me right now so I'm not sure of its usability. Pastebin is an option but there isn't consolidated code there. Would creating a Dropbox account be the best way to share code easily?

**EDIT:**

Ok, these responses have me swimming in words I'm not familiar with, but I'm greatly appreciative of all this knowledge being bestowed upon me. How can I simplify sharing code by having one student give another student a .java file and he uses that .java file, and all its public methods, to help make his project work?

For example, one student makes a simple math operations class. Another student makes a different math operations class. They share code with one another and are able to implement the other person's class to create a simple calculator.

Comment: Use SVN. It still rocks.

Comment: Git, Mercurial, SVN etc. are just meant to do that - Dropbox isn't. And they are integrated with eclipse with plugins. Bitbucket or Github are simply online repositories. It definitely is the way to go. Build a simple one class project, add another class, commit, fetch, merge etc. and you will soon understand how they work.

Comment: So you have students, but don't know what good are versioning systems with regards to sharing code among independent developers?

Comment: If it is non-trivial for professionals to learn source-control, why teach it to high school students when they are probably in over their heads in Java?

Comment: The authors of Subversion publicly admit that they prefer Git.

Comment: @skynorth because it is proven to work, they don't have to re-invent the wheel, what probably wouldn't be easier. And VCS concepts are not so hard to understand.

Comment: @Pruce I know we all like to pretend this is an ideal world, but they can't teach students everything. It is the same reason why people don't teach high school other "proven" concepts, enterprise IDE's, Ant (automated testing), Maven (dependency injection), JIRA (project tracking), Agile/Scrum, waterfall (software development methodologies). It is not necessary at this point, it is beyond the scope.

Comment: @skynorth well, maybe it's a cultural misunderstanding, but if the OP writes "student" I'm reading "university". At university/ Bachelor student level, learning a VCS is not asked for too much, IMHO. Of course after they learned basic programming, but before they start working in teams.

Comment: @skynorth oh, I missed that, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Dropbox/Google Drive seems to be the best option for what they need to do. I would love to do other things but the focus of the class is understanding the programming language. Maybe when I become comfortable with Git we'll use that. Right now it's all about coding and sharing a class with another student.

Everyone was awesome with this. Thanks for all the great ideas and discussions.

Answer (score 7):

If you teach programming you should really be aware:

- Of the importance of collaboration and versionning tools like Git, Mercurial, SVN
- That there is currently a massive shift to git

Your students should be able to use a versionning system after their cursus, or they will lack a skill that is very important when it come to working together.

Since there is a currently a big scale move to git, why not having them learn git? I recommend you to read [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book) and learn them to use git. GitHub is the simplest way to make a git server available for them.

Neither you nor them will learn it in 5 mins, but for them, and for you as a teacher it's worth the investment.

Comment: Isn't github a payed service?

Comment: @Skidrow if your project is open-source then yes it is free to host.

Comment: Well, I think vc is a bit overkill. Ftp and webdav is much simplier.

Comment: Who the hell are you to tell someone they failed at their job. I know we all like to pretend this is an ideal world, but there are practically no high schools in the country that teach source control, and the 4 competent universities I've been at, don't teach it either. People 20-30 years ago survived without version control, and they can now. Why don't we teach the important fundamentals first, before jumping into side material. This is the kind of unnecessary topics (in high school) that will get kids turned off programming.

Comment: Apparently, I didn't understand the magnitude of my question until I got these responses. I've never done version control so I have a lot of reading to do just for myself, let alone my students.

Comment: @skynorth I did say "partially", and it's a conditional form. Plus, collaboration is not a "side skill". Actually it's the most important thing in programming. Programming in the real world is more a communication exercise than a technical exercise. Think about the ratio of the time spend reading code + talking about code + modifying code / writing brand new code. Knowing how to exchange code with others and do it the right way is just a part of that. Publishing changes in atomic commits with a proper comment, like correctly naming a function is as important as other more technical aspects.

Comment: @tazboy I'm really sorry if the words "partially failed" hurt you. Believe me, that was not my purpose. Is was just a way to highlight the dire importance of that point when working for a long time with other people.

Comment: @SamuelRossille If you said that Dennis Ritchie, he would laugh at you.

Comment: @SamuelRossille: I don't think programming is an communication skill it's a most likely a design process. Unfortunately it's not seen like this and it's often not good payed. Also there is many bad people in this business.

Comment: @skynorth Actually you are right, I don't know the concrete situation and the constraints so I'm not in a position to judge and I'm not allowed to talk about failure. This was unjustified, rude, and out of topic, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

I find sourceforge very convienent. It's free and also has a small webserver. Maybe it's older and not that hyped like git. But I understand your worries and a ftp or a webdav protocol is also good to share code. Komodo IDE for example can edit files over ftp. Version control can be really painful and you need to learn much.

Answer (score 2):

I am a college student, so this might be kind of awkward. But in my opinion, using a source control might be the best option, although it might be hard to understand the new concepts that lay ahead. But in the long run, every employer wants their programmers using some source control. In addition, maybe use some tools that allows them to communicate even when they are not near, like TeamViewer, Skype, etc.

My opinion Mercurial, and my favorite client that integrates with Explorer on Windows TortoiseHg.

Answer (score 2):

Use a version control system, best a distributed one (DVCS) like Mercurial or Git.

It should be qutie easy to run a "main" Mercurial repository over the network, e.g. using `hg serve` and I guess it would be similarly easy with Git.

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories2

https://www.mercurial-scm.org

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/quickstart

If your students start to work in teams, also make sure they get the concepts of:

- Continuous Integration, e.g. using Jenkins

and therefore also:

- automated builds, e.g. using Maven
- automated unit tests, e.g. using JUnit

Comment: pure distributed way (pull-exchange) is, IMNSHO, better and even more easy way

Comment: And how do you realise Continuous Integration, to make sure your code always builds and passes the tests, in order not to block other developers?

Comment: do I want it? Or was it requested? Or does it (permanent hg serve + hg pull) contradicts CI-mantras? CI fashion buzzword in a lot of cases

Comment: OK, but my answer was about recommending also to consider CI and I guess this only really works if you have a "main" repository.

Comment: "Or does it (permanent hg serve + hg pull) contradicts CI-mantras?" Maybe I didn't understand your comment then...

Comment: 1. CI works in any environment, if you'll be able to provide sources for integration - in any way 2. CI, TDD is a subject of another courses, I think, not "first steps in code-monkey bloody work". VCS in discussed case is minimal needed costs

Comment: I'm still not getting your first point, but about your second point: I think altough CI, automated builds and unit testing should be learned after basic programming, at the time when you start to work in teams (as it's the case here) they definitivly become important topics (not necessarily TDD, yet, which is not the same as unit testing).

Comment: Note that it might be good, if the teacher/ prof and his/ her team would do the setup of the CI and provide initial Maven POMs/ Ant scripts. But getting used to look at a CI (not configuring it) is important for team work.

Answer (score 1):

If your students are using Windows, then I suggest that you use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/).  It is based on Subversion source code control system, also known as SVN.

You would have to setup the repository. The student's computers would need to have Tortoise SVN installed, and configured to attach to the repository.

You would then teach the students good principles of source code control--a skill vital for any programming project, especially those projects where collaboration is used.

Comment: I would have given a -1. Why only Windows? TortoiseSVN is just a GUI tool to handle the repository... But again, even this bad answer is a hint in the right direction...

Comment: The other thing is, people start to move in the direction of DVCS such as Mercurial and Git, as they have proved to be more flexible.

Comment: @ppeterka: TortoiseSVN is a Windows only product. It is an extension to the Windows Explorer. My answer is not a bad answer.  Many High Schools only use Windows. TortoiseSVN is not as powerful as Git and Mercurial, but it is *very* easy to use.  The repository can reside on any computer that supports Subversion, but TortoiseSVN only runs on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

- Using VCS in today's professional programming is a **must**
- VCS is a best way for sharing and collaborating in code-development
- If each subtask is performed *by a group*, DVCS for free P2P communications in process in a **Natural Way**
- Git is worst choice for newcomers in SCM-world

SVN has minimal learning course (but some additional weight in technical support of process), Mercurial (pure hg or TortoiseHG) has minimal amount of technical support (zero), but slightly more learning course, compared to SVN. Fossil SCM has somehow intermediate values, but will be useless for students in future, but provide not only SCM, but some additional features in process (embedded wiki as source of knowledge exchange)

Comment: @tazboy - if separate class is separate file, they can use any ol' not-good file-exchange methods - FTP, network-shares, e-mail attachments...